# Python number of files with specific file size ranges

Tags: python, linux, file, python-2.7, scripting

I am trying to write a script that will traverse through my directory and sub directory and list number of files in a specific size. For example 0kb-1kb: 3, 1kb-4kb:4, 4-16KB: 4, 16kb-64-kb:11 and goes on in multiples of 4. I am able to get list of file numbers, size in human readable format and find number of files in a size group. But i feel my code is very messy and not anywhere near to the standard. Need help in refurbishing the code

```
import os
suffixes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB']
route = raw_input('Enter a location')


def human_Readable(nbytes):
        if nbytes == 0: return '0 B'
        i = 0
        while nbytes >= 1024 and i < len(suffixes)-1:
                nbytes /= 1024.
                i += 1
        f = ('%.2f' % nbytes).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
        return '%s %s' % (f, suffixes[i])


def file_Dist(path, start,end):
        counter = 0
        counter2 = 0
        for path, subdir, files in os.walk(path):
                for r in files:
                        if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path,r)) > start and os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path,r)) < end:
                                counter += 1
        #print "Number of files less than %s:" %(human_Readable(end)),  counter
        print "Number of files greater than %s less than %s:" %(human_Readable(start), human_Readable(end)),  counter
file_Dist(route, 0, 1024)
file_Dist(route,1024,4095)
file_Dist(route, 4096, 16383)
file_Dist(route, 16384, 65535)
file_Dist(route, 65536, 262143)
file_Dist(route, 262144, 1048576)
file_Dist(route, 1048577, 4194304)
file_Dist(route, 4194305, 16777216)
```

Comment: this would be better suited on code review.

Comment: EWit means [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for improvement.

- It is often more useful to supply information as a command line argument instead of prompting for it.
- It is more efficient to count all files in one walk through the directory tree than walking the tree repeatedly for the several size groups.
- Since the size limits form a regular sequence, they can be computed and need not be written down individually.
- Your program does not count files with a size equal to a group limit; though it correctly states this by saying *greater than* and *less than*, I find it more useful not to omit those files.
- `os.path.getsize()` fails for broken symbolic links; I'd use `os.lstat().st_size`, which yields the correct in-tree size of the link file.

This is a version of the program with the above suggestions implemented. Note that it still ignores files with a size from 16 MiB up - this could also be improved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import math
import os
import sys
route = sys.argv[1]

suffixes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB']
def human_Readable(nbytes):
        if nbytes == 0: return '0 B'
        i = 0
        while nbytes >= 1024 and i < len(suffixes)-1:
                nbytes /= 1024.
                i += 1
        f = ('%.2f' % nbytes).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
        return '%s %s' % (f, suffixes[i])

counter = [0]*8             # count files with size up to 4**(8-1) KB
for path, subdir, files in os.walk(route):
    for r in files:
        size = os.lstat(os.path.join(path, r)).st_size
        group = (math.frexp(size/1024)[1]+1)/2
        if group < len(counter):
            counter[group] += 1
start = 0
for g in range(len(counter)):
    end = 1024*4**g
    print "Number of files at least %s less than %s:" \
          %(human_Readable(start), human_Readable(end)), counter[g]
    start = end
```

I think the line `group = (math.frexp(size/1024)[1]+1)/2`, which yields the index for the counter list element corresponding to `size`, warrants some explanation. Consider

```
>>> sizes = [0]+[1024*4**i for i in range(8)]
>>> sizes
[0, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536, 262144, 1048576, 4194304, 16777216]
>>> [math.frexp(s/1024) for s in sizes]
[(0.0, 0), (0.5, 1), (0.5, 3), (0.5, 5), (0.5, 7), (0.5, 9), (0.5, 11), (0.5, 13), (0.5, 15)]
>>> [math.frexp(2*s/1024) for s in sizes]
[(0.0, 0), (0.5, 2), (0.5, 4), (0.5, 6), (0.5, 8), (0.5, 10), (0.5, 12), (0.5, 14), (0.5, 16)]
>>> [math.frexp(3*s/1024) for s in sizes]
[(0.0, 0), (0.75, 2), (0.75, 4), (0.75, 6), (0.75, 8), (0.75, 10), (0.75, 12), (0.75, 14), (0.75, 16)]
```

We get the picture that by picking the base 2 exponent of the float representation of size in KB and adjusting it a bit (`+1` because the mantissa is in the interval `[0.5, 1[` instead of `[1, 2[`, and `/2` to convert from base 2 to base 4) we can compute the proper counter list index.